# Grammar: as vs like

Tags: meaning, syntax, as-like

I'm an English learer. I have a little question. Is it correct to say that sometimes the words "**as**" and "**like**" have the same meaning in the colloquial English?

Instead of saying "I have been teaching spanish since 2010", is it possible to say "I have been working **as** a Spanish teacher" or ""I have been working **like** a Spanish teacher"?

Do those mean different things?

Comment: When you say, "As a teacher...", you are a teacher.  When you say, "like a teacher, you may not be a teacher, but you act like a teacher."

Comment: @RamPillai thank you very much! So for example if someone  native spanish speaker who used to do a different job and had to change his job doing teacher could say "I have been working like a spanish teacher" because he started to teach without any pedagogical background. Is that right? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: "I have been working like a Spanish teacher" is so unnatural-sounding that most Anglophones would judge it to be an error for "I have been working as a Spanish teacher".  "I have been working like a ..." usually has prepositional complements '[a] dog/donkey/horse' or '... slave/Trojan' or ' ... maniac/madman/crazy ...' (idioms meaning 'very hard'). _like_ = _just as hard as_ (in general, _in the same manner as_). Prepositions are very tricky in their behaviour. 'Like father, like sun' / 'As for you, my lad ...' /...

Comment: [ 'acting like a chairman' vs 'acting as a chairman'](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/difference-between-act-as-someone-and-act-like-someone.2552969/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I have been working as a Spanish teacher"
> "I have been working like a Spanish teacher"

@RamPillai is right in his comments.

In your further comments on a person who does Spanish teaching without pedagogical background, as long as he works as a teacher, he should say the same way:

> "I have been working as a Spanish teacher"

Comment: Thank you so much! @Seowjooheng Singapore :)